# SQL Query to return records with certain conditions in several columns, and where only one record with a certain value exists

Tags: sql, sql-server

First, the SQL Server query I'm using:

```
SELECT InfoSource
FROM dbo.orders
WHERE Price IS NULL
  AND Date IS NULL
  AND Expiry IS NULL
GROUP BY InfoSource
HAVING COUNT(InfoSource) = 1
```

Many records can have the same `InfoSource` value. I am attempting to return the value of any `InfoSource` where there is only and exactly one record that exists for that `InfoSource`, and the `WHERE` conditions are met within that one record.

The problem is, after I run this query, I take the results and do a `SELECT` statement on them just to verify the records meet the conditions, but many of the `InfoSource` values exist in more than one record. If there is more than one record for a given `InfoSource`, the query should not be returning that `InfoSource` at all regardless of the `WHERE` conditions.

Do I somehow have my `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` misplaced?

Comment: Does your checking query contain also the same WHERE clause?

Comment: Kristjan's answer does exactly what I need.  Thanks.

Comment: Your query should do what you need.

Comment: It does now that I've updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the query should not be returning that InfoSource at all regardless of
>   the WHERE conditions

At the present, the `where` clause is executed before the `having` clause.

What you need is for it to be executed after.

```
select * from
dbo.orders
WHERE Price IS NULL
AND Date IS NULL
AND Expiry IS NULL
AND InfoSource in (SELECT InfoSource
    FROM dbo.orders
    GROUP BY InfoSource
    HAVING COUNT(InfoSource) = 1)
```

Comment: Glad to be of help :D